# Android Studio: generating a signed APK

Tags: android-studio

I have Android Studio for (Mac) installed on my Mac. It work fine untill I come to generate a signed APK. Clicking on "Biuld+Generate Sign APK" the window opens, if I then click on "Create", the "Create window open behind the first window. No matter what I do I cannot get to the second window.

Has anyone else had this happen? If so how did you get around the problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Not sure how but it's working.